# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: filesystem

My python program was running and then it reported the error mentioned in the title when performing some writing operations. The weird thing is both `df -h` and `df --inodes` showed the main disk (/dev/sda) where my python environment and data files reside is far from being full, as following:

```
(base) rzh@sun-System:~$ df -h
????        ??  ??  ?? ??% ???
udev             63G     0   63G    0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  3.1M   13G    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  458G   31G  404G    7% /
tmpfs            63G  769M   63G    2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      2.5M  2.5M     0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/748
/dev/loop1      384K  384K     0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
/dev/loop2      256M  256M     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop3      2.3M  2.3M     0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop4       30M   30M     0  100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop5      1.0M  1.0M     0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop7       56M   56M     0  100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/sda        3.6T  1.9T  1.6T   55% /mnt
tmpfs            13G  8.0K   13G    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop8       56M   56M     0  100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop9       31M   31M     0  100% /snap/snapd/9721
/dev/loop10     2.5M  2.5M     0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/826
/dev/loop11     384K  384K     0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/570
/dev/loop12     218M  218M     0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
tmpfs            13G   36K   13G    1% /run/user/1005
tmpfs            13G   72K   13G    1% /run/user/1004
/dev/loop13      65M   65M     0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
tmpfs            13G     0   13G    0% /run/user/1007
tmpfs            13G   16K   13G    1% /run/user/121
tmpfs            13G  4.0K   13G    1% /run/user/1003
/dev/loop14      65M   65M     0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
tmpfs            13G     0   13G    0% /run/user/1006
```

and

```
(base) rzh@sun-System:~$ df --inodes
????           Inode ??(I)   ??(I) ??(I)% ???
udev            16444257     725  16443532       1% /dev
tmpfs           16450232    1482  16448750       1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  30531584  246711  30284873       1% /
tmpfs           16450232     462  16449770       1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           16450232       5  16450227       1% /run/lock
tmpfs           16450232      18  16450214       1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0          1351    1351         0     100% /snap/gnome-calculator/748
/dev/loop1           230     230         0     100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
/dev/loop2         24339   24339         0     100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop3           784     784         0     100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop4           463     463         0     100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop5           355     355         0     100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop7         10775   10775         0     100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/sda       244195328 6611979 237583349       3% /mnt
tmpfs           16450232      20  16450212       1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop8         10779   10779         0     100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop9           472     472         0     100% /snap/snapd/9721
/dev/loop10         1384    1384         0     100% /snap/gnome-calculator/826
/dev/loop11          230     230         0     100% /snap/gnome-characters/570
/dev/loop12        18513   18513         0     100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
tmpfs           16450232      35  16450197       1% /run/user/1005
tmpfs           16450232      48  16450184       1% /run/user/1004
/dev/loop13        63811   63811         0     100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
tmpfs           16450232      12  16450220       1% /run/user/1007
tmpfs           16450232      25  16450207       1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           16450232      17  16450215       1% /run/user/1003
/dev/loop14        63978   63978         0     100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
tmpfs           16450232      12  16450220       1% /run/user/1006
```

Any ideas on this?